# Transfer recorded camera video (using Media Recorder) in videoView of next activity in android

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera, uri, surfaceview

How to transfer camera recorded video in next activity and play video onClick of videoView of next activity?

Camera functions performs with use of Media Recorder.

Currently having NullPointerException when **Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference(According to log).**

how to resolve this issue.
This is my code :

First Activity

```
public class AndroidVideoCaptureExample extends Activity {
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mPreview;
    private MediaRecorder mediaRecorder;
    private Button capture, switchCamera;
    private Context myContext;
    private LinearLayout cameraPreview;
    private boolean cameraFront = false;
    String mFileName;
    Intent mediaIntent;
    boolean isPlaying = false;
    Uri url;
    long maxduration = 10000;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    Uri videoUri;
    private static final int CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE = 200;

    //  for timer
    private TextView timerValue;
    private long startTime = 0L;
    private Handler customHandler = new Handler();

    long timeInMilliseconds = 0L;
    long timeSwapBuff = 0L;
    long updatedTime = 0L;

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        myContext = this;
        initialize();
    }

    private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the front facing camera
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                cameraId = i;
                cameraFront = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    private int findBackFacingCamera() {
        int cameraId = -1;
        // Search for the back facing camera
        // get the number of cameras
        int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
        // for every camera check
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
            CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
            Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
            if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                cameraId = i;
                cameraFront = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return cameraId;
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (!hasCamera(myContext)) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone does not have a camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
            finish();
        }
        if (mCamera == null) {
            // if the front facing camera does not exist
            if (findFrontFacingCamera() < 0) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                switchCamera.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            mCamera = Camera.open(findBackFacingCamera());
            mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
        }
    }

    public void initialize() {
        cameraPreview = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);

        mPreview = new CameraPreview(myContext, mCamera);
        cameraPreview.addView(mPreview);

        capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        capture.setOnClickListener(captrureListener);

        switchCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_ChangeCamera);
        switchCamera.setOnClickListener(switchCameraListener);

        timerValue = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer);
    }

    OnClickListener switchCameraListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // get the number of cameras
            if (!recording) {
                int camerasNumber = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
                if (camerasNumber > 1) {
                    // release the old camera instance
                    // switch camera, from the front and the back and vice versa

                    releaseCamera();
                    chooseCamera();
                } else {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(myContext, "Sorry, your phone has only one camera!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.show();
                }
            }
        }
    };

    public void chooseCamera() {
        // if the camera preview is the front
        if (cameraFront) {
            int cameraId = findBackFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId >= 0) {
                // open the backFacingCamera
                // set a picture callback
                // refresh the preview

                mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                // mPicture = getPictureCallback();
                mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
            }
        } else {
            int cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
            if (cameraId >= 0) {
                // open the backFacingCamera
                // set a picture callback
                // refresh the preview

                mCamera = Camera.open(cameraId);
                // mPicture = getPictureCallback();
                mPreview.refreshCamera(mCamera);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // when on Pause, release camera in order to be used from other
        // applications
        releaseCamera();
    }

    private boolean hasCamera(Context context) {
        // check if the device has camera
        if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    boolean recording = false;
    OnClickListener captrureListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (recording) {


                String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(mFileName);
                String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                Intent mediaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                mediaIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(mFileName), mimeType);
                startActivityForResult(mediaIntent,CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);



                // stop recording and release camera
                mediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
                releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
                Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCaptureExample.this, "Video captured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                recording = false;


            } else {
                if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {
                    Toast.makeText(AndroidVideoCaptureExample.this, "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    finish();
                }
                // work on UiThread for better performance
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        // If there are stories, add them to the table

                        try {

                            mediaRecorder.start();


                        } catch (final Exception ex) {
                            // Log.i("---","Exception in thread");
                        }
                    }
                });

                recording = true;
            }
            startTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
            customHandler.postDelayed(updateTimerThread, 0);

        }
    };

    private Runnable updateTimerThread = new Runnable() {

        public void run() {

            timeInMilliseconds = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - startTime;

            updatedTime = timeSwapBuff + timeInMilliseconds;

            int secs = (int) (updatedTime / 1000);
            int mins = secs / 60;
            secs = secs % 60;
            int milliseconds = (int) (updatedTime % 1000);
            timerValue.setText("" + mins + ":"
                    + String.format("%02d", secs));
            customHandler.postDelayed(this, 0);

        }

    };

    private void releaseCamera() {
        // stop and release camera
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }


    private void releaseMediaRecorder() {
        if (mediaRecorder != null) {
            mediaRecorder.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mediaRecorder.release(); // release the recorder object
            mediaRecorder = null;
            mCamera.lock(); // lock camera for later use
        }
    }

    private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {


        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
        String i = sdf.format(new Date());
        mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        mFileName += "/audiorecordtest" + i + ".mp4";
        mCamera.unlock();
        mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration((int) maxduration);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(90);
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
        //  mediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED()
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(mFileName);


        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            releaseMediaRecorder();
            return false;
        }

        mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(new MediaRecorder.OnInfoListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {


                    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(mFileName);
                    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
                    Intent mediaIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    mediaIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(mFileName), mimeType);
                    startActivityForResult(mediaIntent,CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE);

                    mediaRecorder.stop();
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        mediaPlayer.reset();
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.setDisplay((SurfaceHolder) mPreview);

                    try {
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(mFileName);
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode==CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {

            videoUri = data.getData();  // get the uri of video from intent
            launchUploadActivity1(true,videoUri);
//  
//          }
        }
    }

    private void launchUploadActivity1(boolean isPlaying, Uri uri) {

        Intent i = new Intent(AndroidVideoCaptureExample.this, SecondLast.class);
//      i.setData(uri);  // set the uri to intent
        i.putExtra("play",videoUri);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

Second Activity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    boolean pausing = false;;
     Uri file;
   VideoView video;


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       final Uri videoUri = getIntent().getData();  // do anything from the Uri
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second_last);

        ImageView buttonPlayVideo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        Intent i = getIntent();
        file = Uri.parse(i.getExtras().get("play").toString());

        video.setVideoURI(file);
        video.start();





        buttonPlayVideo.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent i = getIntent();
                file = Uri.parse(i.getExtras().get("play").toString());

                video.setVideoURI(file);
                video.start();


            }});
    }

}
```

//Preview class

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        mCamera = camera;
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);

//      mHolder.setFixedSize(176, 144);

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }



    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            // create the surface and start camera preview
            if (mCamera == null) {
                assert mCamera != null;
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
                mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
                mCamera.startPreview();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error setting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void refreshCamera(Camera camera) {
        if (mHolder.getSurface() == null) {
            // preview surface does not exist
            return;
        }
        // stop preview before making changes
        try {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
        }
        // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
        // reformatting changes here
        // start preview with new settings
        setCamera(camera);
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mHolder);
            mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);


            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(VIEW_LOG_TAG, "Error starting camera preview: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        // If your preview can change or rotate, take care of those events here.
        // Make sure to stop the preview before resizing or reformatting it.
        refreshCamera(mCamera);
    }

    public void setCamera(Camera camera) {
        //method to set a camera instance
        mCamera = camera;
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     mCamera.release();
        mHolder.getSurface();

    }
}
```

My current code recoded the video according to requirement and play just after recording.But in second activity it does nothing.

Comment: you can pass the Uri of the video in the intent to another activity

Comment: I want some sample ,because I have tried several thing which I know as u can see in the code.

Comment: Debugging help questions require a [mcve] as per the [help]. Your code is not minimal. Please [edit] your question to make sure that your code is Minimal (only the code necessary to reproduce your issue in your question), Complete (users do not need anything else to reproduce your issue), and Verifiable (the provided code does reproduce the exact issue you are facing). As it is your question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Note that this is also a common [downvote reason](http://idownvotedyoubecause.com/so/TooMuchCode).

Comment: This is just for over all scenario,

Answer (score 2):

**In your activity's onActivityResult method get the uri and send it to the upload activity:**

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode==CAMERA_CAPTURE_VIDEO_REQUEST_CODE) {
        launchUploadActivity1(true);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // video successfully recorded
            // launching upload activity
            Uri videoUri = data.getData();  // get the uri of video from intent
            launchUploadActivity1(true,videoUri);
        }
    }
}

private void launchUploadActivity1(boolean isPlaying, Uri uri) {
    Intent i = new Intent(AndroidVideoCaptureExample.this, SecondLast.class);
    i.setData(uri);  // set the uri to intent
    startActivity(i);
}
```

**And in your SecondLast activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle b){
  super.onCreate(b);
  Uri videoUri = getIntent().getData();  // do anything from the Uri
}
```

Comment: After playing video it still stops

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=200, result=0, data=null} to activity camlimit.AndroidVideoCaptureExample}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.net.Uri android.content.Intent.getData()' on a null object reference

Comment: See! You are recording the video through your camera object. From the Recorded video send the uri as data first from your camera activity then only you will get it there!